# Fontes das funções padrões de Python

Tags: python, funções, python-2.7, cpython

Tem como eu descobrir o algoritmo por traz de funções como `split()` e `in` em Python, pois na minha faculdade existem algumas funções proibidas.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível ver a [`split()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/459cd61399f589caccae1c0fa2138ebcaaa63ea6/Objects/stringlib/split.h#L54), mas não vai ter servir para nada.

Tem outras variações dela.

O `in` é um operador e não uma função. Tem o código fonte dele no Github, um pouco mais difícil achar, mas pelo menos agora você sabe onde tem.

Minha recomendação é que você faça o que o exercício pede e não procure atalhos, a ideia deles não é copiar de algum lugar (e note que nem procurar você conseguiu), o objetivo é entender o problema e produzir um algoritmo da sua cabeça, só assim aprenderá programar. Copiar coisas prontas até um computador pode fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Em Python na verdade não tem como.

Python é uma linguagem interpretada, muito menos eficiente do que linguagens como C ou Java. Para melhorar seu desempenho, grande parte da biblioteca padrão de Python foi implementada em código nativo, ou seja, não existe um código em Python por trás do split, existe apenas código de máquina já compilado, que não é humanamente compreensível.

Comment: Hmmmm, quase tudo que você falou aqui é errado? A implementação mais comum de Python é escrita em C, portanto por trás tem sim um código legível. Também tem outras variações, como o Jython, o IronPython, PyPy, versões pra navegadores e a lista segue. Todos com código legível para humanos. Além de tudo, Python é (como uma boa linguagem de programação) Turing Completa, portanto toda e qualquer computação Python pode fazer